# How do I remove the first <tr> from a table in beautifulsoup4 (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have the below python script where table variable holds the entire html. The trfirst has the first row element which is my headers. I want to remove the trfirst from table and put this into a new variable so I can retrieve the row values. I am using BeautifulSoup4.

HTML example looks like this:

```
<tr>
<td> 
<div> Header 1</div> 
</td>
<td> 
<div> Header 2</div> 
</td>
<td> 
<div> Header 3</div> 
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> 
<div> Row 1</div> 
</td>
<td> 
<div> Row 1</div> 
</td>
<td> 
<div> Row 1</div> 
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> 
<div> Row 2</div> 
</td>
<td> 
<div> Row 2</div> 
</td>
<td> 
<div> Row 2</div> 
</td>
</tr>
```

Python:

```
url = "C:/Test.html"
html = open(url, "r", encoding='utf-8').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='lxml')
table = soup.select_one("table")
trfirst = table.find("tr")
**trrest = ??? (table - trfirst)**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use nth-child and nth-child ranges to separate the headers from the body

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''your html'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml') # 'html.parser'
headers = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('tr:nth-child(1) td div')]
print(headers)
data = [[j.text.strip() for j in r.select('td div')] for r in soup.select('tr:nth-child(n+2)')]
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try slicing -> `BeautifulSoup(sample_html, "html.parser").find_all("tr")[1:]` where your slice is `[1:]` which skips the `header` part.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample_html = """
<tr>
<td> 
<div> Header 1</div> 
</td>
<td> 
<div> Header 2</div> 
</td>
<td> 
<div> Header 3</div> 
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> 
<div> Row 1</div> 
</td>
<td> 
<div> Row 1</div> 
</td>
<td> 
<div> Row 1</div> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 
<div> Row 2</div> 
</td>
<td> 
<div> Row 2</div> 
</td>
<td> 
<div> Row 2</div> 
</td>
</tr>
"""

for row in BeautifulSoup(sample_html, "html.parser").find_all("tr")[1:]:
    print(row.select_one("td div").getText())
```

Output:

```
 Row 1
 Row 2
```